# Third-party Login

Tags: facebook

I have a website that accepts Facebook login. When the user clicks the FB login button, it logs the user into his/her FB, retrieves the user info, and uses that info to login the user at my own backend. After successful login, the page jumps to the main site. For logout, it's the same. I first log the user out of his Facebook, and then out of my own backend (flush the session).

The problem is that the FB login at my site gets mixed with Facebook sessions at other places. If a Facebook loggedin user logs out (`FB.logout()`), his/her Facebook website will also be logged out. And if the user has logged in his FB somewhere else, when he comes to my site, the FB login button shows a already-logged-in state. But the `getLoginStatus()` actually shows the status as `'unknown'` instead of `'connected'`, so the page doesn't jump. He has to logout, and then login again, which is pretty weird.

I wonder if there's a descent way to handle this, separating FB sessions at different places. This also applies to other third party authentication issues.

Comment: Any news related to that issue ?